# Identification of a red arachnida (?) (picture and video)

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, arachnology

I found this in a greenhouse in Norway. It is a few millimeters in size, I could fit 5-6 of them on my thumbnail.

[image: Creature for identification]

It looks a lot like this one from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trombidiformes

Can someone help me identify it? Is it a parasite or a harmless creature?

Also a video of it moving around

https://1drv.ms/v/s!AlmW2TG6jr_7ga4eTDLz7qzKM4W_8w

Update:

I found a link [description](https://www.terminix.com/pest-control/ticks/identification/red-tick/) which makes me think it is a mite (same as the Wikipedia link).

> One of the most common sources of confusion between ticks and mites is color. No known species of naturally occurring red tick exists. But ticks can sometimes appear to be red if they’re in the act of feeding. However, the spider mite, red velvet mite, clover mite and the larvae of the harvest mite—known colloquially as chiggers—all take various shades of red.

Comment: It might also be a type of predatory mite -- these are frequently used in organic or IPM agriculture to control spider mites. See for example this [wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phytoseiulus). I would talk to someone at the greenhouse and see whether they release predatory mites.

Comment: looks like a tick to me

Comment: @aminabzz I thought it looked like a tick as well, but I have never heard of red ones or seen a description of one. Going to update the question with a reference regarding that.

Comment: it is clover mites here is a video about them: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BftGk-S2GyU